# How to filter through a defaultdict?

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

i'm learning python to go through data. I have a CSV input file that I organized as a defaultdict.

It looks like this :

```
{
 '1234' : [('1,60', 'text', 'supplier1')],
 '3456' : [('1,98', 'another text', 'supplier2')],
 ['1,54', 'text again', 'supplier1'],
 '709' : [('2,90', 'again', 'supplier2')] 
}
```

What I would like to is priorize tuples containing for instance "supplier1". If there is results for the same key for supplier1 and 2, keeping only supplier1. And if no results for a given key for supplier1, keeping results with other suppliers.

EDIT : desired output :

```
{
 '1234' : [('1,60', 'text', 'supplier1')],
 '3456' : ['1,54', 'text again', 'supplier1'],
 '709' : [('2,90', 'again', 'supplier2')] 
}
```

How would be the best way to do that ? I don't want to keep only supplier1 result

Comment: Please reformat the dictionary structure to be more readable.

Comment: Defaultdict is not the appropriate way to organize this file ? I need to keep the number (such as 1234) as a key

Comment: I edited to include desired output but dont understand which syntax I have to correct ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `defaultdict` is a subclass of `dict`, we can assume a regular dictionary of lists (at the same time, I've fixed some syntax errors which I assume are typos):

```
d = {'1234' : [('1,60', 'text', 'supplier1')],
     '3456' : [('1,98', 'another text', 'supplier2'),
               ('1,54', 'text again', 'supplier1')],
     '709' :  [('2,90', 'again', 'supplier2')]}
```

You can then use a dictionary comprehension with a custom function to perform your task:

```
def get_data(x):
    for tup in x:
        if tup[-1] == 'supplier1':
            return [tup]
    return x

res = {k: get_data(v) for k, v in d.items()}

{'1234': [('1,60', 'text', 'supplier1')],
 '3456': [('1,54', 'text again', 'supplier1')],
 '709':  [('2,90', 'again', 'supplier2')]}
```